# Does appcelerator studio work without internet connection once its installed?

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, offline, titanium-alloy

```
My system specifications are : 

 Operating System Name         = Mac OS X

      Version                     = 10.10

      Architecture                = 64bit

      # CPUs                      = 4

      Memory                      = 4294967296

    Node.js

      Node.js Version             = 0.12.4

      npm Version                 = 2.10.1

    Titanium CLI

      CLI Version                 = 4.0.1

    Titanium SDK

      SDK Version                 = 4.0.0.GA

      SDK Path                    = /Users/systemname/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/4.0.0.GA

      Target Platform             = iphone
```

The problem that i am facing is that i need continous internet connection for launching the app on device.Is there some setting which i can make to run without internet connection?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I have interpreted your question correctly you are looking for something like [this post from the appcelerator page](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/119830/use-titanium-withour-internet-connection-or-logged-off).

To cite the top answer, you have to "locate the TitaniumStudio.ini file from Titanium Studio installed directory. Add the following at the end of the file `-Dtitanium.bypassAuthentication=true"`.

On Windows 8 it should be located at `C:\Users\<YourName>\AppData\Local\Titanium Studio`